# Is "Behind this lowland is a dead end." grammatically correct?

Tags: writing-style

Is "Behind this lowland is a dead end." grammatically correct?
I'm also wondering about the difference in meaning and delivery between this sentence and "There is a dead end behind this lowland."
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both of

> - Behind this lowland is a dead end.
> - There is a dead end behind this lowland.

are grammatically valid, and their meaning is much the same. The first emphasizes the lowland, the second the dead end. Either could be a literal statement, or some sort of metaphor. Without more context one cannot say, nor judge which would work better.